# Datastream - TimeWindow for past date

Tags: time, stream, apache-flink, data-processing

I have dataset with past Event Time

```
01-12-2015 01:10:10
01-12-2015 01:10:20
01-12-2015 01:10:30
01-12-2015 01:10:40
.... (millions of records)
```

I want to apply timeWindow for this `timeWindow(Time.seconds(30))`

I can have a TimeExtractor class to get the `EventTime` in the data. But how do I implement `getCurrentWatermark` method. It should get the past date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it would be best to use one of the provided `TimeStampAssigners` see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#pre-defined-timestamp-extractors-watermark-emitters).

So what I would recommend is something like this:

```
DataStream<MyEvent> stream = ...

DataStream<MyEvent> withTimestampsAndWatermarks =
stream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<MyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public long extractAscendingTimestamp(MyEvent element) {
        return element.getCreationTime();
    }
});
```

Also remember to set proper `TimestampCharacteristic`:

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```